# Excel INDEX MATCH repeats only first value

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to populate a new Excel table from the table below based on Yes/No criteria:

```
ACCOUNTNO    AUTODRAFT
0001         No
0002         Yes
0003         No
0004         Yes
0005         Yes
```

My formula:

```
=INDEX(AccountNo,MATCH("Yes",AutoDraft,0))
```

Returns:

```
0002
0002
0002
0002
0002
```

When I would like it to return:

```
0002
0004
0005
```

Comment: Do you need a formula? You could just filter on the `AUTODRAFT` column for value `Yes` and then copy/paste the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter formula with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(AccountNo,SMALL(IF(Autodraft="Yes",ROW(AccountNo)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable if there are blank cells in between the results on the new worksheet? Without VBA or manually sorting the first data set, I'm not sure how to eliminate the spaces.

However, this formula works:  `=IF(ISNA(MATCH("Yes",B2,FALSE)), "", A2)`

Screenshot:

[image]

If you sort your first data set:

[image]